# Grunt watch with default

Tags: gruntjs, watch

I have configured Grunt and have now added a watch task to run certain tasks when specific files have been changed. However, I wish to run a number of tasks first and then for the watching to start.

How can I do this?

My current watch task is:

```
watch: {
    javascripts: {
        files: ['app/assets/javascripts/**/*'],
        tasks: ['javascripts']
    },
    stylesheets: {
        files: ['app/assets/stylesheets/**/*'],
        tasks: ['stylesheets']
    },
    svgs: {
        files: ['app/assets/svgs/**/*.svg'],
        tasks: ['stylesheets']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could register a custom task as an alias of tasks you wanted to perform.

```
grunt.registerTask('yourTaskName', ['yourOtherTask', 'yourOtherTask2', 'watch']);
```

and then run it like this:

```
grunt yourTaskName
```

Comment: Will have a go at this. Thanks.